# numbering subfigures

Tags: floats, numbering

I've got three figures that I place vertically on a half page.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/fig1a.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/fig1b.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/fig1c.png}
\end{figure}
```

I want to subnumber them and put the (a), (b) and (c) at the corners of the images. All three figures are of different resolutions and sizes. It's hard do that and get them vertically aligned in the resulted pdf. So, my question is if there is a proper tool or package to do this automatically?

Regards
Ilya

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try the `subfigure` environment, from the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Which corner?  Lower left is easiest.

Comment: Ideally upper right or left.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few details which can be painful to discover, since some are from the caption manual.  The blank lines (`\par`) are needed to keep them from winding up side by side.

You said different sizes.  Although the MWE uses known sizes, this will work for images with unknown sizes. `\subcaptionbox` does this automatically (thank you Alex Sommerfelt for pointing this out), but it is no big deal. All subfigures are basically minipages with captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}% measure width
\begin{subfigure}{\wd0}
\usebox0
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}% DIY caption
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
\leavevmode\llap{(c)~}% left
\usebox0
(c)
\end{minipage}
\caption{There is usually one of these too.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

These solutions puts the subcaption at the upper right corner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedleft,position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}% measure width
\begin{subfigure}{\wd0}
\caption{}
\usebox0
\end{subfigure}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}% DIY caption
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}% in case you want to align side by side
\strut\makebox[\wd0][r]{(c)}\par% above
\usebox0%
\rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht0-\topskip}{(c)}}% right
\end{minipage}

\caption{There is usually one of these too.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo 2]

Comment: You write "The subfig package does this automatically". This is true, but the `subcaption` package does this automatically, too, when `\subcaptionbox` is used instead of the `subfigure` environment.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt -  Ah yes.  An even better reason to stop using subfig.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest of all methods is to use the `subfigure` package, that adjusts to the desired dimensions of your images, althought it has problems with `tikz`, so I avoid it, but it works wonderfully with imported graphics

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[Subcaption a.]{\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\subfigure[Subcaption b.]{\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Subcaption c.]{\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete package. instead of it is suggested to use the `subfig` package.